# Why does only one out of two multibindings work?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, multibinding

I am using a `MultiBinding` in two different points in my XAML. Here is the code:

```xml
<StatusBarItem>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="X " />
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CoordinateToStringConverter}" TargetNullValue="-">
                    <Binding Path="ChartMouseX" />
                    <Binding Path="AxisSettingsViewModel.XAxisSettings.LabelFormat" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text=" Y " />
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CoordinateToStringConverter}" TargetNullValue="-">
                    <Binding Path="ChartMouseY" />
                    <Binding Path="AxisSettingsViewModel.YAxisSettings.LabelFormat" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</StatusBarItem>
```

I am facing a weird issue. The first `MultiBinding` works perfectly, but the second one is never called. If I comment out the first `MultiBinding`, the second one starts to work as expected.

Is this some kind of limitation in WPF? Or am I missing something about multibindings?

P.S: The `RaisePropertyChanged` is correctly invoked. However, in the second binding the converter does not get called at all.

**EDIT**

Here is the code of the Converter:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace LogViewer.Converters
{
   public class CoordinateToStringConverter : IMultiValueConverter
   {
      #region IMultiValueConverter members

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values != null && values.Length == 2)
        {
              object value = values[0];
              string format = values[1].ToString();

              if (value is DateTime)
                  return ((DateTime)value).ToString(format);

              if (value is TimeSpan)
                  return ((TimeSpan)value).ToString();

              if (value is double)
                  return ((double)value).ToString(format);
          }

          return null;
      }

       public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
          throw new NotImplementedException();


       #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work when switching them both, i.e. making Y before X?

Comment: @poke: you are right... but now I am getting really confused... why is it working in one way and not in the other? :/

Comment: You mean, *both* are working if you switch them around? I did not expect that :o

Comment: @poke: unfortunately, yes, they work both when switched around... what could be the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: could you include the code for CoordinateToStringConverter? In the meantime you could try putting a debugging converter on the Bindings inside the multibinding and see if the convert gets hit.

Comment: @user1834059: hey there, as you requested, I've posted the converter code. As I said before, the converter gets hit only when dealing with the X value but not when it should handle the Y value, unless the two bindings are switched over or the very first one is commented out.

Comment: Could ChartMouseX ever return null? if so then trying to use it in the converter would throw a NullReferenceException, so when it's called first, it never gets to Y, but when it's called second, it at least gets to the `Convert` function for a second time before throwing the exception...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, try making a an exact copy of the CoordinateToStringConverter and x:Key it to CoordinateToStringConverter2 or w/e. Then use different value converters for each MultiBinding.

Answer (score 1):

I have analyzed your issue. Which is working fine for me. Nothing wrong with the multibinding.
Have you checked the converter with breakpoint was it called two times. Otherwise your problem is in ChartMouseY and ChartMouseX.[image]